# Sheimos-free versions of Tanach Online

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet, shemos-sacred-names

There are many websites that provide the user with the text of Tanach (as well as various other Jewish sources). When printing sources, I like to avoid printing "Sheimos", or actual names of Hashem, such as יהוה, אלהים, שדי,  etc.

Are there any versions of the text free online that automatically remove God's name  from the text by replacing them with יקוק, אלקים, שקי or other alternatives? I have seen that a couple of websites replace some names of God with י"י, but they still leave others intact. I am looking for a site that has a version without names  such as אל, צבאות, which often times remain even on those sites.

Comment: i'm assuming you want it for printing purposes in which case there should be no copyright attached to the text as well..

Comment: Would you accept a program that takes in any such text and outputs a Sheimos-free version, or are you specifically looking for a website that’s ready to print?

Comment: @user15464 Yes, that would be the case

Comment: @DonielF you are welcome to post it as an answer, but I generally find/replace any sheimos on whatever text I use, so it won't be that much more helpful.  It would also be very tedious to edit out words like אלהים, which are sometimes Chol (non-holy) or אדני, which can be vowelized in different ways

Comment: Which is why a program would be much easier - if it’s just a passuk or two is one thing, but if it’s the entire Torah at once...?

Comment: @DonielF I do it with smaller chunks of text...

Comment: Just to be constructive, here's an exemple with Word: יְהוָ(?)ה -> יְקוָ\1ק Obviously you can do fancier stuff with a proper regex engine instead of Word's wildcards, although you can't filter out the אלקים אחרים type cases...

Comment: How about filtering out the sheimos posted in your question?

Comment: @user218076 why?

Comment: Words processors have a find and replace feature, just a thought